# trigger on button click by keyboard input

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently writing in C# wpf and I would like to imitate the action of clicking a button by the user pressing a key.

```
private void abuttonispressed(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
                {
                    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control) && (e.Key == Key.S)) 
                    {
                        //click event is raised here
                    } 


                }
```

It's vital that not only the code of that button is run but also the visual 'clicking' of the button. I read about this and suggestions like performclick were made but performclick is not a known method for the button somehow...

Any ideas?

Comment: I don’t see why it should be the case, much less “vital”, that the button be visibly depressed when you press a key combination. No other UI I’ve seen does that. If you’re doing it just for the sake of being different, novel or creative, it should ring an alarm bell and you should reconsider it.

Comment: It's not a matter of being different or creative, I simply want the user to be able to control the application with the keyboard and get visual feedback so they know what they activated.. There are many UI's doing this, the most obvious example being pressing enter on a selected button to activate it's click function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the right answer, but would start playing from here:

```
private void abuttonispressed(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control) && (e.Key == Key.S)) 
    {
        //click event is raised here
        button1.Focus();
        button1.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent, button1));
    } 
}
```